# Can you say that $Sp\{v\} \cup Sp\{w\} = Sp\{v,w\} - Sp\{v\cap w\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it correct to write the union of two spans as the span of the vectors from the two spans minus the intersection between the two spans?

i.e.

> $Sp\{v\} \cup Sp\{w\} = Sp\{v,w\} - Sp\{v\cap w\}$

Comment: At least, $0$ does not belong to the RHS as opposed to the LHS.

Comment: $v\cap w$ doesn't make sense since $v$ and $w$ are vectors...

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true. Cansider the case $v=w.$

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you understand what the symbols mean:

[image]